# Android-Listener between two fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hello guys 
 I have two fragments displayed within the same activity, 
 The first one is the map, and the second one is the menu which contains switches. 
 My question is that any method to update the map automatically when a switch is turned on or turned off ? 
 For example any solution with Listeners or something like that ??

Comment: Thank you @MohammedAtif, it works fine

Comment: why was this question downgraded? The person who downgrades should be required to justify via a comment the downgrade. Otherwise, there is not much value added to this voting feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say, Fragment 1 has to be updated when a switch is turned on/ off in Fragment 2.

**Method 1:**

Write a method in Fragment 1 to update it's view. Since, both Fragments are in the same activity you can get the instance of the fragment from the activity using a getter. In Fragment 2, get the instance of Fragment 1 & call the update method.

**Method 2:**

Use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to post event from Fragment 2 & handle it in Fragment 1.

**Method 3:**

Use interfaces. You may write an interface in Fragment 2 with an update method. In Fragment 2 call this method on switch on/ off & implement it in Fragment 1.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your response, i tried the first method and it works for me

Comment: Most welcome! :) Please mark my answer as accepted.